# recording the steps taken of minimum sum path in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, dynamic-programming

say i have a matrix [[1, -2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 6]], and i have to find the path with the smallest sum traveling from top left to bottom right.

i used the dp method below(by making another table and adding up on the cells traveled):

```
new_tr[0][0] = mat_tr[0][0]
for j in range(1, N):
    new_tr[0][j] = mat_tr[0][j] + new_tr[0][j - 1]
for i in range(1, M):
    new_tr[i][0] = mat_tr[i][0] + new_tr[i - 1][0]
for i in range(1, M):
    for j in range(1, N):
        new_tr[i][j] = min(new_tr[i - 1][j], new_tr[i][j - 1]) + mat_tr[i][j]
        print(new_tr[i][j])
```

I want to record each of the step taken to get the smallest sum. (e.g. (right, down, down, right) in the case of [[1, -2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 6]])

what is a way that i can do so?

Comment: You wrote "traveling from top right to bottom left" but the desired output seems like you are assuming travelling from top left to bottom right. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following recursive approach:

```py
mat = [[1, -2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 6]]

def smallest(mat, x=0, y=0):
    # mat: nested list for the matrix
    # x, y: current position
    # output: tuple (val, path)
    #         val: smallest value from the current position to the destination
    #         path: list. path to the destination
    rows, cols = len(mat), len(mat[0]) # size of the matrix
    if (x, y) == (rows - 1, cols - 1): # if arrived at the southeast corner
        return mat[x][y], []
    candidates = [] # store results from deeper calls
    if x < rows - 1: # if we can go down
        candidates.append([*smallest(mat, x + 1, y), 'down'])
    if y < cols - 1: # if we can go right
        candidates.append([*smallest(mat, x, y + 1), 'right'])
    candidate = min(candidates, key=lambda u: u[0]) # pick the smaller result
    return mat[x][y] + candidate[0], [candidate[2], *candidate[1]]

print(smallest(mat)) # (8, ['right', 'down', 'down', 'right'])
```